# Unexpected token '<'

Tags: html, css, unexpected-token

recently i was trying to open my old projects which were error free a while ago and now I am finding this error Syntax error:Unexpected token'<' in all of my html files at the very first line as I am beginner I am seeking out for help all of my files with error contain html and css only
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
The above image represents the error

I tried by reinstalling nodemon modules.I even checked every line of code I even tried removing ""line but then the error came on the second line ""

I am running a local server,its not a template.I dont know why is it being evaluated

^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v21.4.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: a) Please post your error as text, not an image, b) what are you doing? Are you running a framework? Or just a local server? Why _is_ your html being 'evaluated'? It doesn't look like a template?

Comment: Doesn't `nodemon` expect a _script_ to execute?

Comment: a)i have updated it above b)just a local server ,I dont know why my html was being evaluated it was not showing any error a while ago when i opened this file on my new user its displaying the above error , its not a template @somethinghere

Comment: Show us how you are “trying to open my old projects”.

Answer (score 2):

Nodemon is to serve the javascript files. Instead you can use http-server to run your html files:

Here is how you can install it:

`npm i -g http-server`

And run this command in the your directory:

`http-server`

You don't even need to specify index.html, as it looks for the file by same name.